# Why we use this syntax for NCB in C?

Tags: c, pointers, structure, netbios, ncb

I have a question about NetBios NCB (Network Control Block).I wonder why we can use this syntax, as shown example below, if the structure doesn't have any pointers.

```
UCHAR reset( NCB *block ) {
    block->ncb_command = NCBRESET;
    block->ncb_lana_num = 2;
    block->ncb_lsn = 0;
    block->ncb_num = 0;
    Netbios(block);
    return block->ncb_retcode;
}



int main()
{
   NCB blok;
   UCHAR err;

   printf ( "reset:");
   err = reset(&block);
   if ( err != NRC_GOODRET ) {
   printf ( "ERROR %x\n" , err ) ;
   } 
   else {
   printf ( "SUCCEED ! (%x)\n", err) ;
   };
}
```

The structure of NCB looks like this:

```
typedef struct _NCB {
   UCHAR  ncb_command;
   UCHAR  ncb_retcode;
   UCHAR  ncb_lsn;
   UCHAR  ncb_num;
   PUCHAR ncb_buffer;
   WORD   ncb_length;
   UCHAR  ncb_callname[NCBNAMSZ];
   UCHAR  ncb_name[NCBNAMSZ];
   UCHAR  ncb_rto;
   UCHAR  ncb_sto;
   void   (CALLBACK *ncb_post)( struct *NCB);
   UCHAR  ncb_lana_num;
   UCHAR  ncb_cmd_cplt;
   UCHAR  ncb_reserve[X];
   HANDLE ncb_event;
} NCB, *PNCB;
```

sorry for my English.

Comment: Looks like Microsoft types. Strong hint: avoid it like the plague.

Comment: Which syntax are you talking about exactly?

Comment: I'm talking about reset funtion. Why we have to use "->" and why we not create any pointer in main function and then do not use allocation?. Just only NCB block; ?

Comment: "not create any pointer" - er, you know what `&block` does, right?

Comment: yes I know it contains the address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `->` syntax is used on `block` because `block` is a pointer (its type is `NCB*`, which means "pointer to `NCB`").

Whether or not the `NCB` structure contains any pointers as fields does not matter because `block->ncb_command` does not dereference the `ncb_command` field - it dereferences `block`, which is a pointer.